# Rewrite rules per site in one htaccess file

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there a way in an htaccess file to write rules that only work for a specific site? So if I have 2 sites pointing to the same directory I just want to write rules for the first site and not the second site. I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitea\.com
RewriteRule ^site-url http://www.sitea.com/site-url.php [R=301,L]
```

The problem is siteb.com also follows the rule above. Am I doing something wrong? Or can this not be done? I only have access to the htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different filename for the site that you want to ignore it: see http://www.electrictoolbox.com/change-htacces-filename-apache/

But that requires being able to edit the VirtualHost configuration, which access you do not have?

If you're only using it for rewrites, though, the rewrite condition should be specific enough so that it doesn't affect the other site.

Comment: I thought RewriteCond will only run the rules if the current domain matches the condition, otherwise it will skip all the rules underneath that condition?

Comment: What Im trying to do is use the same redirect but different results for different sites. So I want sitea.com for a specific page to go to pag1.html and then I want siteb.com with the same url to go to page2.html

Comment: yes, your rewrite rules should be able to be written in such a way that this is possible. do you have access to the raw Apache logs on your server? that might help debugging if so.